# What is the keyboard shortcut to fix the spelling of a word in Chrome in MacOSX?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, spell-check

MacOSX unfortunately lacks a context menu keyboard key.  Mozilla projects have adapted ctrl-space so that when your keyboard cursor is on a misspelled word, you can press crtl-space to open the context dialog and select the proper spelling without using the mouse.  OpenOffice offers shift-F10 to do this.

Is there a keyboard shortcut to do this in chrome?

Comment: The ⌘+: (COMMAND+COLON) shortcut no longer works for me in Chrome! :( I have version 16.0.912.75 ... used to use it all the time. Now I have to right-click on words, choose Spell-checker options then Spelling Panel to get to the panel that used to open with ⌘+: ... anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The keyboard shortcut to correct a spelling on the Mac version of Google Chrome is <kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>:</kbd> (`COMMAND-COLON`).

Google maintains a [complete list of keyboard shortcuts in Chrome for Mac](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/165450?hl=en).

Comment: This isn't actually what I mean by a context menu shortcut (which is nicer for doing dynamic spelling correction as opposed to opening a separate dialog).  Regardless, it looks like this is the closest thing for Chrome on the Mac, so I'm marking this answered.  Thanks for the link.

Comment: This shortcut does not appear to work in Chrome anymore and the link appears broken...

Comment: @Andrew: I updated the link.  This keyboard shortcut is still listed there.  If it's not working, [do let them know](http://chromiumbugs.appspot.com/).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Command-:` for *Edit » Spelling and Grammar » Show Spelling and Grammar*. It's the same keyboard shortcut as in almost any other Mac program.

If you want to change it, open *System Preferences » Keyboard » Keyboard Shortcuts » Applications*, enter `Chrome` (or `All Applications`), `Show Spelling and Grammar`, and your desired shortcut.

Answer (score 2):

The misspelled word should have a space after it and the little wiggly red lines should be under the word.

Using the arrow keys, move to the end of the word and then wait.

You should see a list of words appear under the misspelled word. You can now use the arrow keys (down, left, right) to highlight the correct spelling and press <kbd>return</kbd> to select it.

Comment: What version of chrome are you using?  This doesn't work for me (chrome 18.0.1025.11)

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + (<kbd>Fn</kbd>) + <kbd>f10</kbd> (depends what you have the fn button functionality as)